# Netlogo: How do I flatten a list of lists of lists?

Tags: list, netlogo

I can do the following:

```
> set one-deep [[3] [3] [1] [3] [2]]
> reduce sentence one-deep
: [3 3 1 3 2]
```

But how do I flatten deeper lists of lists ... of lists?

```
> set two-deep [[1] [3] [1] [2] [[1] [1] [2] [3] [3]] ]
  ???
: [1 3 1 2 1 1 2 3 3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure that your list of lists in only two-deep, you can simply do:

```
reduce sentence reduce sentence two-deep
```

But if you want a more general solution, something like this should work:

```
to-report unnest [ xs ]
  let ys reduce sentence xs
  report ifelse-value (reduce or map is-list? ys) [ unnest ys ] [ ys ]
end
```

The `(reduce or map is-list? ys)` expression makes heavy use of NetLogo concise anonymous procedure syntax, but it simply means "is any item in `ys` a list?"

Comment: I had to work through that syntax a bit, I think I understand it now. `map is-list? ys` returns a list of booleans. The `reduce` is going through that list of boolean elements, left to right, applying the `or` for the current element (a boolean) and the next one (also a boolean) in the list over and over until it's exhausted all elements, ultimately returning a single boolean value. Thus, if any of the elements are `true` in the list, `reduce` will return a `true`. Very nice, I'm sure I'll refer to this again!